# Terraform with Localstack basic setup doesn't work

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, localstack

I want to try basic setup for localstack with terraform.
My docker-compose file, from the localstack [docs](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53"                # DNS config (only required for Pro)
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53/udp"            # DNS config (only required for Pro)
      - "127.0.0.1:443:443"              # LocalStack HTTPS Gateway (only required for Pro)
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME=localhost
      - PERSISTENCE=${PERSISTENCE-}
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-}
      - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY-}  # only required for Pro
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - SERVICES=s3
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

My terraform file to create s3 bucket

```
# Public Cloud Configuration
provider "aws" {
  region                      = "us-east-1"
  access_key                  = "test123"
  secret_key                  = "testabc"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  endpoints {
    s3 = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}

# Create Bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "bucket"
}
```

I got the next error when running the command terraform apply

```
│ Error: creating Amazon S3 (Simple Storage) Bucket (bucket): RequestError: send request failed
│ caused by: Put "http://bucket.localhost:4566/": dial tcp: lookup bucket.localhost on 10.222.50.10:53: no such host
│
│   with aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket,
│   on main.tf line 15, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket":
│   15: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
```

I'm able to create s3 bucket manually in the localstack with command like
`aws --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://user-uploads`

docker ps output

```
c9497bcff0e3   localstack/localstack       "docker-entrypoint.sh"   23 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes (healthy)   127.0.0.1:53->53/tcp, 127.0.0.1:443->443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:4510-4559->4510-4559/tcp, 127.0.0.1:4566->4566/tcp, 127.0.0.1:53->53/udp, 5678/tcp   localstack_main
```

So why localstack is trying to access some different address like `192.168.178.1:53`? Do I need to specify somewhere different address? Checked a number of tutorials and for everyone, the setup works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue herein lies with your Terraform configuration. The following code inside `main.tf` works perfectly with `tflocal` (LocalStack's wrapper for Terraform CLI):

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "bucket"
}
```

```bash
tflocal init
tflocal apply
```

If you don't wish to use `tflocal`, you would need to have a configuration like this:

```
provider "aws" {

  access_key                  = "mock_access_key"
  secret_key                  = "mock_secret_key"
  region                      = "us-east-1"

  s3_force_path_style         = true
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true

  endpoints {
    s3             = "http://s3.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test-bucket" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Checking with native terraform, this gives another error `caused by: Put "http://s3.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/bucket": dial tcp: lookup s3.localhost.localstack.cloud on 192.168.178.1:53: no such host`

Comment: Using tf local gives similar error `│ caused by: Put "http://bucket.s3.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/": dial tcp: lookup bucket.s3.localhost.localstack.cloud on 192.168.178.1:53: no such host
│` Seems like it searching for the `192.168.178.1:53` but that address isn't available. What the address for and where it is configured? Shouldn't it be `127.0.0.1:53` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it adding a property in provider aws

**s3_use_path_style = true**

Sample:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
  backend local {}
}

provider "aws" {
  region                      = "localhost"
  access_key                  = "local"
  secret_key                  = "local"
  skip_region_validation      = true
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true
  s3_use_path_style           = true // <<- this property here

  endpoints {
    dynamodb = "http://localhost:4566"
    s3   = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}

// S3
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
  bucket = "teste"
}
```

I hope help you

Comment: Note that "path style" as enabled here is [deprecated in AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)